# Unable to sync the Zune software with my HTC HD7

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, sync, windows-phone, zune-software

I have a brand new HTC HD7 with Windows Phone 7, with no Software installed.

I am running on Windows 7 64 bit. Whenever I try to sync my Mobile Device with Zune- I get this message:

> Can't connect to your phone. Disconnect it, restart it, then try connecting again

I've downloaded latest Zune software and all updates.

I don't have any certificates on my personal certificates.  My phone is listed under Portable devices in Device manager (It shows as phone with driver version 4.7.965.0).

I've restarted both my computer and the mobile device few times. I tried unlocking the device during the Zune sync

Any ideas as to how I can sync my phone ?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

- Hard resetting the phone, which will erase all information in it.  I'm not sure how to do this... if I find out in time I'll edit this.
- Uninstall the entry in Device Manager (by right clicking), reboot, and then connect the device, letting the driver reinstall.
- Reinstall the Zune software

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a Samsung Focus and followed these steps from the following link to resolve it, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468307

Cause:

There's an issue with the Zune personal digital certificate. Your digital certificate is your Windows Phone's unique identifier, and is used to sync with the Zune software.

Resolution:

To resolve this issue, you have to create a new certificate. Here's how:

1. If your Zune software is open on your computer, close it and disconnect your phone from your computer.
2. Open Certificate Manager. To do this, click Start, type certmgr.msc in the Start search bar and press Enter.
3. Click the Personal folder and then the Certificates folder.
4. Click the heading that says Issued By to sort the column, and then look for one or more certificates that is issued to "zune-tuner://windowsphone/...".
5. Right-click that certificate, click Delete and then click Yes.
6. From the File menu, click Exit.
7. As soon as you're done, open your Zune software and connect your phone to your computer. This creates a new certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I am a computer lab tech with a Windows HTC 7 phone. If your sync is not coming up after you reset your phone or for other reasons you sometimes might have to change the USB cable to get synching to work.  Also, check the `Control Panel` under `System` and `My Hardware` then `Device Settings`.  You need to make sure the USB device drivers are loaded.

Comment: I've had trouble with a camera being recognized, until I used the cable from my scanner:  It  has ferrite cores on both ends of the cable, which helps quell noise from electrical interference or ground loops.